# How to eliminate spaces in matlab while a function displays an answer

Tags: matlab, formatting

Code:

```
A = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10];
M = mean(A)
```

Output:

```
M =
   5.5000
```

I want it to be on 1 line like:

```
M = 5.5000
```

Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your code to this:

```
A = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]; M = mean(A); fprintf('M=%f\n',M);
```